# Try to get base exception in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have code to perform [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) operation through python.

```
# Filename: models.py
from uuid import uuid4

from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns


class StudentModel(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'students'
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name = columns.Text(index=True, required=True)

    def __json__(self):
        return {'id': str(self.id),
                'name': self.name}
```

I am using this `model` in another file.

```
# Filename: test.py

from cassandra.cqlengine import query
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table

from models import StudentModel

# Create Connection
connection.setup(hosts=['192.168.99.100'],
                 default_keyspace='test',
                 protocol_version=3)

# Sync database table to create table in keyspace
sync_table(StudentModel)


StudentModel.create(name='test')
StudentModel.create(name='test')

try:
    StudentModel.get(name='test')
except query.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    print "MultipleObjectsReturned"
except query.DoesNotExist:
    print "DoesNotExists"
except StudentModel.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    print "Local Exception"
```

I created 2 record for same name  and it has to raise `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

But when I run this, it return me `DoesNotExists`, I check the code for `get` function from where this exception raise https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py#L753.

```
try:
    self[1]
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned('Multiple objects found')
except IndexError:
    pass
```

When I check, inheritance for this it is `self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned -> cassandra.cqlengine.model.MultipleObjectsReturned -> cassandra.cqlengine.query.MultipleObjectsReturned` in this inhritance, there is no `DoesNotExists`

Why it catch in `DoesNotExists` exception?

`cassandra.cqlengine.query.MultipleObjectsReturned` is super class of `cassandra.cqlengine.model.MultipleObjectsReturned` then why code not execute for first catch block ?